# bootstrap label is next to button but should be above it

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want my register button to be under the label, but it's coming up next to it..

```
<span class="label label-info">No account yet?</span>
<button id = "registerBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="window.location.href='/register/'">Register now!</button>
```

And it looks like this right now - [image]

I want it so the Register Now! button is under the label..

Answer (score 0):

`span`s are inline elements.  You can either change it to a block element such as `div` or you can just insert a `br` between them to force it to the next line.

If this is in a bootstrap form, then you'll need to include all the surrounding markup as well to get a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

`span` is `inline` type by default. If you change it to `block`, it will work as you want :

```
span.label-info {
  display: block; 
}
```